# Adding a lag in R data frame with panel data that has some missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I am trying to lag one variable in my panel data. I have the following structure where often many values are missing from the first few years.

```
| ID  | Year | x  |
| --- | -----|----|
| 1   | 2000 | NA |
| 1   | 2001 | 56 |
| 1   | 2002 | 51 |
| 2   | 2000 | 45 |
| 2   | 2001 | 46 |
| 2   | 2002 | 40 |
```

I want the lagged data to look as follows

```
| ID  | Year | x  | Lag_x |
| --- | -----|----|-------|
| 1   | 2000 | NA |  NA   |
| 1   | 2001 | 56 |  NA   |
| 1   | 2002 | 51 |  56   |
| 2   | 2000 | 45 |  NA   |
| 2   | 2001 | 46 |  45   |
| 2   | 2002 | 40 |  46   |
```

I am using the following code for lagging the data, however, it doesn't seem to be working, instead it just shows a new column with a new name but with the same data.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Lag_x = lag(x))
```

Naturally, my actual data has multiple other columns that I am also using, but that do not need to be lagged.

Thank you for any possible help!

Comment: When I run your code on your data, I get your expected output. If you don't, check to make sure that you're using the correct lag function: if replacing `lag` with `dplyr::lag` works, then you've been inadvertently using `stats::lag`, which is far different. Another way to check: type in `lag` on the console and hit enter; if the console output ends with `<environment: namespace:dplyr>` then you're using the correct version of `lag`, otherwise you may see `<environment: namespace:stats>` or another package.

Comment: FYI, assuming you were unknowingly using `stats::lag`, one might wonder why it took precedence over `dplyr::lag`? The answer is almost always "order the packages are loaded". If after `dplyr` is loaded you explicitly called `library(stats)` (should not need this), or a package you might be side-loading (e.g., via `devtools::load_all`) explicitly imports some of all from the `stats` package, it will be bumped earlier in the search path and therefore masking `dplyr::lag`. Many find it useful to incorporate the [`conflicted`](https://conflicted.r-lib.org/) package into their workflow. Good luck!